# PHP error reporting for all */dev directories

Tags: apache-2.2, php, virtualhost

I have an Apache server with multiple webprojects. Every project has a development, and a production site associated like this:

```
/srv/www/project1/dev 
/srv/www/project1/prod

/srv/www/project2/dev
/srv/www/project2/prod

/srv/www/project3/dev
/srv/www/project3/prod
```

Every project also has a virtual-host file - this is for project 1:

```
# Prod
<VirtualHost 123.45.789.123:80>
    ServerAdmin john@doe.com
ServerName www.johndoe.com
DocumentRoot /srv/www/project1/dev
</VirtualHost>

# Dev
<VirtualHost 123.45.789.123:80>
    ServerAdmin john@doe.com
    ServerName dev.johndoe.com
DocumentRoot /srv/www/project1/dev

    # enable php error_reporting for development site
<Directory /srv/www/project1/dev>
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_value error_reporting 214748364
        php_flag display_errors 1
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything is working fine like this. However, I find it redundant to add the IfModule mod_php5.c part to all virtual hosts. Is it possible to add it to the default virtual host file like this (I've tried, and can't make it work):

```
    <DirectoryMatch "^/srv/www/.+/dev">
            <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                    php_value error_reporting 214748364
                    php_flag display_errors 1
            </IfModule>
    </DirectoryMatch>
```

Looking forward to hear your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your **<DirectoryMatch>** block directly to the server config, don't put it inside a **<VirtualHost>** block. Check here for more information about the scope of this directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directorymatch